# How to make application not closeable by home and back button?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make Android application, which can be closed only by buttons in a layout of that app and not with back&home HW/SW buttons?

I want to make one-purpose app for myself, I can set all permissions for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current activity you can overide back buttons function using `onBackPressed` method.

When you press Home button, `onPause` method will be called (activity goes to paused stage). so you can overide it with your custom codes.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing that. That's the whole purpose and concept of the Home button. If you could explain your use-case, may be there are alternate approaches.

Comment: It's like a lockscreen - only me would know, how to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Back button-  override onBackPressed and do not call super.onBackPressed.  I don't think you can do home, but you can try trapping the keystroke.